# Windows 7 not keeping extended monitor settings

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a Win7 laptop with dual monitors. The laptop display is disabled, and I use the monitors in extended view. Everytime the laptop sleeps or is undocked, the monitors reset position and resolution. I have removed the TMM file from the registry. Any suggestions how to keep the configuration from resetting each time?

Comment: Please add some information on what laptop your using and what dock your using

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an IBM Thinkpad, you can press the Fn+F7 keys to choose Extended.  This somehow remembers your previous Extended settings as this scenario happens with my laptop all the time.

**EDIT:** You can get to the same spot by going to the Control Panel, choosing Display, then clicking on the 'Connect to a Projector' link.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before on XP.try logging on with a different profile to see if it still happens. In my case it was a corrupted Xp user profile, or bad hardware profile. 
Let me know if this works